# Como Mostrar todos los elementos de un List <String> en C#

Tags: mysql, c#, string, bucle-for, arraylist

Tengo un List <<"String">> que tiene una cantidad de 10 Elementos en total. Yo deseo establecer en una condicional *IF* si la palabra que estoy analizando dentro de un ciclo *FOR* no pertenezca al conjunto de palabras reservadas almacenadas en una lista para establecer que es un identificador

`if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(palabra[j][validar_id]) && palabra[j] != palabras_reservadas[0])`

Habra alguna manera de poner todos los elementos de dicha lista porque la unica forma donde si lo ejecuta es poniendo un index manualmente.

Comment: Puedes usar la función [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0) de la lista para mirar si ese elemento existe dentro de toda la lista o no, seria algo como: `palabras_reservadas.Contains(palabra[j])`

Comment: EXCELENTE SI FUNCIONO !!!

Comment: Dejo comentario por aqui opciones de verificar si es Letter o Digit con un benchmark [Verify is letter or digit (Benchmark in c#) > https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark](https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark), ya que puede servir para mejorar la performance

Answer (score 0):

```
if (char.IsLetter(palabra[j][validar_id]) && (palabras_reservadas.Contains(palabra[j]) == false))
```

Con esto lo solucioné.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a tu pregunta. A los demás no se les notifica cuando respondes: mejor dejar un comentario. Lee [answer], y [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.